# How to scale a Graphics2D image with transparent padding

Tags: java, image, transparency, graphics2d, alpha-transparency

I'm trying to write a small method which takes a `BufferedImage` image and a new width and height and scales the image keeping the aspect ratio by adding transparent border to the left/right or top/bottom depending on the image.  The scaling works fine but for the life of me I can't get the border to be transparent.

So far I have the [following code posted on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/eFarSKqi) which does the scaling well.

I've read a lot of manuals and other SO questions to no avail.   I've tried numerous permutations of fills, composite types, image types, etc..  Sometimes I get a blue background, sometimes white but it never seems to be transparent.

```
BufferedImage newImg = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, img.getType());
Graphics2D g = newImg.createGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.fillRect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
g.drawImage(img, x, y, x + scaledWidth, y + scaledHeight, 0, 0,
    currentWidth, currentHeight, Color.WHITE, null);
g.dispose();
return newImg;
```

Any idea what Graphics2D call I need to make to have the `Color.WHITE` background be transparent *and* draw the old image over the new?  Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**

It turned out that the problem I was having was that I was trying to generate a transparent color with a JPEG image.  JPEGs do not support transparency.  Duh.

Comment: Have you tried to set the alpha component with [`new Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is one of the things that I tried @Eng.Fouad.  If you can be a bit more specific I'll try it out.

Comment: Something like `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Also, consider using `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` as the image type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just tried it out and it works.

Just replace `Color.WHITE` with `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)`, and `img.getType()` with `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`.

---

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));
BufferedImage outImage = scaleWithPadding(img, 300, 100);
ImageIO.write(outImage, "png", new File("newImage.png"));
```

**image.png:** (204x53)

[image]

**newImage.png:** (300x100)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  What type of image did you try?  Is my problem that I'm trying to convert JPEGs?

Comment: @Gray `PNG` image. `JPEG` cannot have transparency within it.

Comment: That was my problem.  Thanks much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same requirement as you and your post and this page on [how to make a color transparent](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0265.html) helped me a lot.

Here is my final code:

```
public BufferedImage getTransparentScaledImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int finalWidth, int finalHeight) {
    int originalWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
    int originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

    int newWidth;
    int newHeight;
    if (originalWidth == 0 || originalHeight == 0
            || (originalWidth == finalWidth && originalHeight == finalHeight)) {
        return originalImage;
    }

    double aspectRatio = (double) originalWidth / (double) originalHeight;
    double boundaryAspect = (double) finalWidth / (double) finalHeight;

    if (aspectRatio > boundaryAspect) {
        newWidth = finalWidth;
        newHeight = (int) Math.round(newWidth / aspectRatio);
    } else {
        newHeight = finalHeight;
        newWidth = (int) Math.round(aspectRatio * newHeight);
    }

    int xOffset = (finalWidth - newWidth) / 2;
    int yOffset = (finalHeight - newHeight) / 2;

    LoggerManager.getInstance().debug("frontoffice",
            "Image Servlet: [" + xOffset + "] [" + yOffset + "] [" + newWidth + "] [" + newHeight + "] [" + originalWidth + "] [" + originalHeight + "] [" + finalWidth + "] [" + finalHeight + "]");

    BufferedImage intermediateImage = new BufferedImage(finalWidth, finalHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D gi = intermediateImage.createGraphics();
    gi.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
    gi.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    gi.fillRect(0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight);
    gi.drawImage(originalImage, xOffset, yOffset, xOffset + newWidth, yOffset + newHeight, 0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight, Color.WHITE, null);
    gi.dispose();

    //if image from db already had a transparent background, it becomes black when drawing it onto another
    //even if we draw it onto a transparent image
    //so we set it to a specific color, in this case white
    //now we have to set that white background transparent
    Image intermediateWithTransparentPixels = makeColorTransparent(intermediateImage, Color.WHITE);

    //finalize the transparent image
    BufferedImage finalImage = new BufferedImage(finalWidth, finalHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D gf = finalImage.createGraphics();
    gf.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
    gf.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    gf.fillRect(0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight);
    gf.drawImage(intermediateWithTransparentPixels, 0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0), null);
    gf.dispose();

    return finalImage;
}

public static Image makeColorTransparent(Image im, final Color color) {
    ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() {
        // the color we are looking for... Alpha bits are set to opaque
        public int markerRGB = color.getRGB() | 0xFF000000;

        public final int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
            if ((rgb | 0xFF000000) == markerRGB) {
                // Mark the alpha bits as zero - transparent
                return 0x00FFFFFF & rgb;
            } else {
                // nothing to do
                return rgb;
            }
        }
    };

    ImageProducer ip = new FilteredImageSource(im.getSource(), filter);
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ip);
}
```

Comment: Thanks u a lot, you have really solved my problem which blocked me a for long time ~

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the mentioned solutions (or very similar) just pay attention if you don't use

```
graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON;
```

your images will be generated with very poor quality (due to scaling)

Answer (score 0):

Your original `drawImage()` method did not have a transparent background because the Color of the background was being used. Replace with the following:

```
 g.drawImage(img, x, y, x + scaledWidth, y + scaledHeight, 0, 0, currentWidth, currentHeight, null);
```