# how to set background transparent when compressing a photo

Tags: java, awt, transparency, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I'm compressing a photo, but an issue blocked me .
it calls drawImage of Graphics2D, but the final output shows that the transparent area of the source photo is copied as black background to the final photo.

why?? how to set background transparent when the area of source photo has a transparent background ??

here is my code :

```
        Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(path + fileName));
        int imageWidth = image.getWidth(null);
        int imageHeight = image.getHeight(null);
        float scale = getRatio(imageWidth, imageHeight, 274, 392);
        imageWidth = (int) (scale * imageWidth);
        imageHeight = (int) (scale * imageHeight);

        image = image.getScaledInstance(imageWidth, imageHeight,
                Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        BufferedImage mBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth,
                imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = mBufferedImage.createGraphics();

        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, null);
        g2.dispose();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path + toFileName);
        ImageIO.write(mBufferedImage, "png", out);
        out.close();
```

Comment: Just a guess, isn't there also TYPE_INT_RGBA?

Comment: there is TYPE_INT_ARGB, but it didn't work yet!!!

Comment: There is a `TYPE_INT_RGB` in the code, and not `TYPE_INT_ARGB`. Apart from that: Why are you creating a scaled instance at all? You can direcly paint the original image (with the desired size) into the target image.

Comment: I don't know about the graphics, so I copied the code from internet... I have found the right answer, thanks you all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070343/how-to-scale-a-graphics2d-image-with-transparent-padding?rq=1 answered by user2458978,  thanks him a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.hb.util;


import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;
import java.awt.image.ImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.ImageProducer;
import java.awt.image.RGBImageFilter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.fusesource.hawtbuf.ByteArrayInputStream;

public class ImageCompressingUtils {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "F:/2huazhuangpin990x395.jpg";
    long c = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ImageCompressingUtils.compress(path, "F:/1.png", "png", 0.8);
    System.out.println("elapse time:"
            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - c) / 1000.0f + "s");
}

public static BufferedImage getTransparentScaledImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int finalWidth, int finalHeight) {
    int originalWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
    int originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

    if (originalWidth == 0 || originalHeight == 0
            || (originalWidth == finalWidth && originalHeight == finalHeight)) {
        return originalImage;
    }

    BufferedImage intermediateImage = new BufferedImage(finalWidth, finalHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D gi = intermediateImage.createGraphics();
    gi.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
    gi.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    gi.fillRect(0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight);
    gi.drawImage(originalImage.getScaledInstance(finalWidth, finalHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), 0, 0, null);
    gi.dispose();

    return intermediateImage;
}

public static Image makeColorTransparent(Image im, final Color color) {
    ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() {
        public int markerRGB = color.getRGB() | 0xFF000000;

        public final int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
            if ((rgb | 0xFF000000) == markerRGB) {
                return 0x00FFFFFF & rgb;
            } else {
                return rgb;
            }
        }
    };

    ImageProducer ip = new FilteredImageSource(im.getSource(), filter);
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ip);
}

/**
 * 压缩
 * @param datas 数据
 * @param rate 压缩比率
 * @return
 */
public static byte[] compress(byte[] datas, String format, double rate) {
    try {
        BufferedImage srcImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(datas));
        int width = srcImage.getWidth();
        int height = srcImage.getHeight();
        BufferedImage descImage = getTransparentScaledImage(srcImage, ((Double)(width * rate)).intValue(), ((Double) (height * rate)).intValue());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(descImage, format == null ? "jpg" : format, out);
        return out.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static void compress(String srcPath, String descPath, String format, double rate) {
    try {
        byte[] datas = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(srcPath));
        byte[] finalDatas = compress(datas, format, rate);
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(descPath), finalDatas);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

it works.